# How can I change ImageView's Image?

Tags: xcode, image, swift, xcode6, imageview

I am trying to make an image change to another image when a button is pressed in xCode 6 in Swift. I have an image view which I have declared as an IBOutlet and have tried to use the command:

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png]
```

But I am getting the following errors on that line of code:

1. Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
2. Expected Decleration
3. Expected expression in container literal
4. Expected ']' in container literal expression
5. Expected an attribute name

Here is my code below:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject) {
        photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"litup.jpeg"]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The errors you are getting is because you are trying to use objective c syntax in swift code.

The `UIImage` in swift has a constructor that takes a `name:String`, however.

In the above where you are setting the image to the imageView you don't need to bother with `if let` as `imageView.image` takes an optional image (`UIImage?`). The if let is only necessary if you will handle the case of getting nil from the constructor `UIImage(name: String)`

```
@IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject) {
    photoImageView.image = UIImage(named:"litup.jpeg")
}
```

should work fine

Comment: I have tried the solution you have provided. I no longer get errors in ViewController.swift but the app still crashes whenever I press the button. When I delete the line the app works fine. Is it possible that a setting in the Identity Inspector or Attributes Inspector could be interfering with the line of code?

Comment: Can you tell me more about the crash? What error do you see when the app crashes?

Comment: Just tried it again a couple of minutes ago and it seems to be working fine. Sorry to bother you and thank you for the help.